# Sublime Text 3 Change Syntax Coloring?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I recently installed Sublime 3, and it's a really neat program, but I haven't been able to find out how to change the colors of the syntax(i.e. block comments, etc)

I've opened Default.sublime-package in Notepad++, and I've found the "Monokai" section(the color scheme I'm using), but even if I change the colors for comments, or even the background, when I open Sublime 3, the colors aren't what I changed them to. I've looked at similar questions on Stack Overflow, but the solutions posted didn't work, and I haven't been able to find anything on Google either.

How can I change the coloring of the syntax, background, etc in Sublime 3?

Answer (score 3):

Use Sublime themes. Monokai is a default theme. You can download any theme you want (for example, from this site: http://devthemez.com/themes/sublime-text-2) and install it. Sublime Text 2 themes mostly work for version 3 either.

First, install `Package Control`. Instructions: https://sublime.wbond.net/installation. It is simple:

- press Ctrl+`
- paste provided string and press `Enter`.

Then clone repository with the theme you want (you need to have some version control system installed, usually it is Git).
In terminal:

- Linux: cd ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages
- Mac: cd ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages
- Windows: cd %appdata%\Sublime Text 3\Packages

If repository is in GitHub, use git: (example with Argonaut theme from devthemez.com, link is provided below)

```
git clone git://github.com/pwaleczek/Argonaut.git 'Theme - Argonaut'
```

Then final step:
In Sublime, open Preferences -> Settings-User and paste appropriate code provided by theme developer: (again, example for Argonaut theme)

```
{
    "theme": "Argonaut.sublime-theme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Argonaut/Argonaut.tmTheme"
}
```

Examples were for Argonaut theme: https://github.com/pwaleczek/Argonaut (this page also contain some sort of instructions for installation).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You've explained how to change the theme, not edit a theme.